# how to send image to server with http.post in javascript and store base64 in mongodb

Tags: javascript, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, base64

I have trouble getting into http requests on the client-side storing images on the server-side using mongodb. I appreciate help a lot. I need an easy example of how i add an image file as data into a http post request such as XMLhttprequest. Lets say, I know the url of the servermethod. The source of the image is defined in

```
imgsrc
```

a name of the file is stored in

```
name
```

I have this atm:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpPost.onreadystatechange = function(err) {
        if (httpPost.readyState == 4 && httpPost.status == 200){
            console.log(httpPost.responseText);
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
var  path = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploadImage/"+name;
httpPost.open("POST", path, true);
// I guess I have to add the imagedata into the httpPost here, but i dont know how
httpPost.send(null);
```

Then on the serverside at the path, the following method will be called and I want to store the url of the base64-encoded image in mongodb. How do I access the image from the httpPost?

```
function postNewImageType(req, res, next){
    var newImageTypeData = {
         name: req.params.name,
         image: "placeholder.png"
    }
    var data = // how to access the image?
    var imageBuffer = decodeBase64Image(data);
    fs.writeFile(cfg.imageFolger+newImageTypeData._id+'.jpeg', imageBuffer.data, function(err){
        if (err) return new Error(err);
        newImageTypeData.set({image:newImageTypeData._id+'.jpeg'});
        var image = new ImageType(newImageData);

    });
    imagetype.save(function (err) {
        if (error) {return next(new restify.InvalidArgumentError(JSON.stringify(error.errors)));}
        else { res.send(201, imagetype);}
    });   
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are a number of ways that you can send your image data in the request to the server, but all of them will involve calling the `send` method of your XMLHttpRequest object with the data you wish to send as its argument.

The `send` method both dispatches the request to the remote server, and sets its argument as the body of that request. Since you're expecting Base64 encoded image data on your server, you'll first need to convert your image file to Base64 data on the client.

The simplest way to convert an image to Base64 on the client is by loading the image as an image element, drawing it to a canvas element, and then getting the Base64 representation of the canvas's image data.

That might look something like the following (given that the URL for the original image is stored in a variable named `imgsrc`, and the desired name is stored in `name` as stated):

```
// This function accepts three arguments, the URL of the image to be 
// converted, the mime type of the Base64 image to be output, and a 
// callback function that will be called with the data URL as its argument 
// once processing is complete

var convertToBase64 = function(url, imagetype, callback){

    var img = document.createElement('IMG'),
        canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        data = '';

    // Set the crossOrigin property of the image element to 'Anonymous',
    // allowing us to load images from other domains so long as that domain 
    // has cross-origin headers properly set

    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous'

    // Because image loading is asynchronous, we define an event listening function that will be called when the image has been loaded
    img.onLoad = function(){
        // When the image is loaded, this function is called with the image object as its context or 'this' value
        canvas.height = this.height;
        canvas.width = this.width;
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        data = canvas.toDataURL(imagetype);
        callback(data);
    };

    // We set the source of the image tag to start loading its data. We define 
    // the event listener first, so that if the image has already been loaded 
    // on the page or is cached the event listener will still fire

    img.src = url;
};

// Here we define the function that will send the request to the server. 
// It will accept the image name, and the base64 data as arguments

var sendBase64ToServer = function(name, base64){
    var httpPost = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        path = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploadImage/" + name,
        data = JSON.stringify({image: base64});
    httpPost.onreadystatechange = function(err) {
            if (httpPost.readyState == 4 && httpPost.status == 200){
                console.log(httpPost.responseText);
            } else {
                console.log(err);
            }
        };
    // Set the content type of the request to json since that's what's being sent
    httpPost.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    httpPost.open("POST", path, true);
    httpPost.send(data);
};

// This wrapper function will accept the name of the image, the url, and the 
// image type and perform the request

var uploadImage = function(src, name, type){
    convertToBase64(src, type, function(data){
        sendBase64ToServer(name, data);
    });
};

// Call the function with the provided values. The mime type could also be png
// or webp

uploadImage(imgsrc, name, 'image/jpeg')
```

When the request is received by your server, the request body will contain the JSON string with your Base64 image within it. Since you haven't provided the server framework or database driver you're using for Mongo, I've adapted your code assuming that you're using Express and Mongoose with an ImageType model already defined in your application.

Since you can always construct the file name of the image record from its `_id` property and your image folder path, it doesn't necessarily make sense to save that as a property on the record, but I've preserved that functionality here, which will require you to save your record twice in one request cycle.

I've also changed the way any errors from the filesystem call are handled. The 'err' you get back from a filesystem error is already an Error object, and will need to be handled by your server in some way.

```
function postNewImageType(req, res, next){
    var json = JSON.parse(req.body),
        newImageTypeData = {
            name: json.name,
            image: "placeholder.png"
        },
        imageBuffer = decodeBase64Image(data),
        newImageType = new ImageType(newImageTypeData);

    //First we save the image to Mongo to get an id

    newImageType.save(function(err){
        if(err) return next(new restify.InvalidArgumentError(JSON.stringify(err.errors)));
        var fileName = cfg.imageFolder + newImageType._id + '.jpeg';

        fs.writeFile(fileName, imageBuffer.data, function(err){
            //Handle error in next middleware function somehow
            if (err) return next(err);
            newImageType.set({image: 'filename.png'});
            newImageType.save(function(err){
                if (err) return next(new restify.InvalidArgumentError(JSON.stringify(err.errors)));
                res.send(201, imagetype);
            });
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! this rly helped me to finally send and save an image! some minor errors in the code, but I could bring everything to work with your help. +1 aswell, cuz I didn't give enough explanations to the frameworks I used.