# How to send image from image Uri through HTTP request? (React Native and Django Backend)

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs, http, react-native

I’m using Expo’s image picker and I’m getting this output:

```
Object {
  "cancelled": false,
  "height": 468,
  "uri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540jbaek7023%252Fstylee/ImagePicker/9a12f0a3-9260-416c-98a6-51911c91ddf4.jpg",
  "width": 468,
}
```

I could render my image, but I just realized that the URL is the **phone’s local URI**.

I’m using Redux-Thunk and Axios to send **HTTP POST request**:

```
export const sendPost = ( imageUri, title, content ) => async dispatch => {
  let response = await axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/rest-auth/registration/`, {
    image, <<<<- I can't put image uri here :( it's LOCAL path
    title,
    content
  })

  if(response.data) {
    dispatch({ type: POST_CREATE_SUCCESS, payload: response.data.token })
  } else {
    dispatch({ type: POST_CREATE_FAIL })
  }
}
```

**UPDATE** I changed a request call

```
let headers = { 'Authorization': `JWT ${token}`};
  if(hType==1) {
    headers = { 'Authorization': `JWT ${token}`};
  } else if (hType==2) {
    headers = { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`};
  }

let imageData = new FormData();
imageData.append('file', { uri: image });
let response = await axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/clothes/create/`, {
    image: imageData,
    text, bigType, onlyMe ...
  }, {headers});
```

!! sorry for the complication but image variable name; `image` is `uri` for the image. I didn't want to change the name of original variable name

and on server, it's printing

```
'image': {'_parts': [['file', {'uri': 'file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent
    /cache/ExperienceData/%2540jbaek7023%252Fstylee/
    ImagePicker/78f7526a-1dfa-4fc9-b4d7-2362964ab10d.jpg'}]]}
```

I found that gzip compression is a way to send image data. Does it help?

Comment: This answer may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/34972537/3514603

Comment: I'm looking into it. But I think React has better option than vanila js

Comment: React is just a UI library. Nothing more and nothing less. And you want to work with XHR. You can use [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) for uploading image if your backend support this format at that endpoint.

Comment: @RadovanKuka I think I have to follow your case. Could you post an answer for me?

Comment: What answer do you mean? I suggested FormData as was suggested also by others or you can convert that image to Base64 as was answered in linked question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is to convert your image to base64 and send the string. Downsize is that usually the base64 strings has a bigger size than the image itself.

Something like this:

```
function readImage(url, callback) {   
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onload = function() {
       var file = new FileReader();
       file.onloadend = function() {
          callback(file.result);
       }
       file.readAsDataURL(request.response);
    };   
    request.open('GET', url);   
    request.responseType = 'blob';              
    request.send(); 
}
```

Comment: React-native-fetch-blob seems great

Comment: When dealing with images I usually just do the base64 because it is much easier. You don't have to deal with bitmaps and you can send it as part of a json object.

Comment: Sounds great. I got the same answer from facebook group. I may edit your answer once I make this worked. I appreciate your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It has to be a local URI, there's no issues with that, how else are you going to point to the image.

Now to upload the image you should first wrap it inside of FormData:

```
// add this just above the axios request
let img = new FormData();
img.append('file', { uri: imageUri });
```

Then inside of your axios request body add:

```
image: img,
```

**EDIT**: This question in it's current form is unanswerable.

I'm using the same Expo’s image picker with React-native in one of my projects as OP and everything works just fine, there's no issues with FormData.

After having talked with OP in a stackoverflow chat, couple of days ago, and stripping the request down to just an image, the server started throwing encoding errors:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 168: invalid start byte
```

So the issue is with OP's Django backend not being setup correctly in parsing the image, and not with the sending of the image itself - which makes the question unanswerable.

Comment: Wow. I hope this works. Let me test it on my computer before I accept it.

Comment: Thanks for your intrest but I'm working on UI part before I send a request. I will test it in 24 hours (hopefully)

Comment: 'image': {'_parts': [['file', {'uri': 'file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540jbaek7023%252Fstylee/ImagePicker/78f7526a-1dfa-4fc9-b4d7-2362964ab10d.jpg'}]]}

Comment: Hi! I'm getting this output on console. I think it's pointing to the image correctly but it's not sending an actual image.

Comment: The image in { uri: image } has to be just the 'uri' portion not the whole image object like you console.log'ed

Comment: sorry for the complication but image is image 'uri'. I didn't want to change the name of original variable name

Comment: You might be missing some headers I'm not familiar with axios so I dont know how helpful it is, but the above definately works when using with fetch, try adding this header:   'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' and on server side you need to have some image processor like Multer that will process the image and add it to req.file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158062/discussion-between-linas-mickevicius-and-john-baek).

Comment: I just included header on the question. Thanks for asking

Comment: I could get current logged in user from header. Header seems ok to me. But I think the way to send an image is not correct :(

Comment: I understand that the request is working, problem is with type, add 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'

Comment: I think something is wrong with header. let headers = { 'Authorization': `JWT ${token}`, 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}; It's giving me 400 error. I'm working on this.

Comment: I think I need to imageData.append(text), imageData.append(bigType) rather than putting imageData as a param

Comment: I think converting image into base64 format will be the best answer. Because it works. Thanks for your input. I appreciate it

Comment: Honestly a lifesaver. I have been revolving around this and finally got an actual solution. Many thanks to you sir/madam

Answer (score 2):

you cant use react-native-fetch-blob .....

```js
import RNFetchBlob from " react-native-fetch-blob"
  PostRequest(PATH){
      RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST', "[URL]", {

            "x-session-id": "SESSION_ID", //or Custom headers
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',

        }, [

                { name: 'image', filename: 'vid.jpeg', data: RNFetchBlob.wrap(PATH) },
                // custom content type

            ]).then((res) => {
                console.log(res)

            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
                // error handling ..
            })
        }
  }
```

for reference [react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob)

Comment: unfortunately Expo doesn't allow to use it

Comment: @JohnBaek any suggestions how to do this in expo?

Comment: @Ma9ic Just stay away from Expo.

Comment: react-native-fetch-blob is no longer available now.