# Can't get POST data from Django (sending it from React)

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, axios

I'm spending hours to solve this problem. The problem is I can't send POST's body data. I'm getting 500 error from the server.

Here is my HTTP request on React Native (I'm thinking I may have wrong axios request). There might be problem on http body?

```
export const createCloth = (token, hType, clothObject) => async dispatch => {
  let headers = { 'Authorization': `JWT ${token}`};
  if(hType==1) {
    headers = { 'Authorization': `JWT ${token}`};
  } else if (hType==2) {
    headers = { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`};
  }

  let {image, text, clothType, ... , onlyMe} = clothObject;

  console.log(text); <- printing ok
  console.log(bigType); <- printing ok

  let response = await axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/clothes/create/`, {

    text, clothType, ..., onlyMe
  }, {headers});

  console.log(response.data); <<< 500 HTTP error
```

Here is my part of Backend API.

```
class ClothCreateAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        # Create Cloth
        # self.request.POST.get('user_id')
        print('--------REQUEST-------')
        print(request)


        logged_in_user = self.request.user
        content = self.request.POST.get('text')
        cloth_type = self.request.POST.get('clothType')
         only_me = self.request.POST.get('onlyMe')
        ...
        print('----------PRINTING CLOTH CONTENT')
        print(logged_in_user) <- printing my username (GOOD)
        print(cloth_type) <- printing None always (BAD)
        print(content) <- printing None always (BAD)
        print(self.request.POST) <- prints <QueryDict: {}>
```

At the last two line, why are they always printing None? I'm checking these syntax back and forth more than twenty times. This is so frustrating

Nothing wrong with self.request.POST.get('somthing') syntax but the reason why it's not working is we have problem on the syntax of **axios request**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By default, axios serializes the request data to json. You can use `json.loads` to deserialize it.

```
import json
data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
```

Alternatively, if you want to use `request.POST`, see the [axios docs] for options to send data in the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format.

Comment: WOW wonderful. Could I ask one more question? Can `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format harm the request any way? I'm sending an image and not familiar with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: or I deserialize the image and it won't matter?

Comment: For non-ajax requests, you use `multipart/form-data` instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for uploads. I'm not sure what the best way of posting an image with an ajax request would be.

Comment: For that matter, I just started a bouty question here if you are interested in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46951617/how-to-include-image-uri-in-http-request

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a djangorestframework to build your views you should be accessing the data through `request.data` rather than `request.POST`.  DRF will automatically parse the json for you and give you access to a dictionary like you are expecting `request.POST` to have.

This also works for other http methods unlike `request.POST`.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/

Comment: you are the life server  :)