# React Native Expo app : can not POST image to Imgur with Axios

Tags: react-native, axios, imgur

I would like to upload a picture from Android Virtual Device to Imgur

I already saw [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46951617/how-to-send-image-from-image-uri-through-http-request-react-native-and-django).

With `ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync()` I get the file :

```
export async function pickImage() {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
        allowsEditing: false,
        aspect: [4, 3],
        quality: 0,
        // base64: true
    });

    if (!result.cancelled) {
        return result.uri
    }
}
```

Now, axios instance creation :

```
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/',
});
```

Now, axios POST :

```
async function postImage(authState, imageUri) {


    //let imageData = new FormData();
    //imageData.append('file', {uri: imageUri});

    await instance({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'upload/',
        data: {
            image: imageUri
        },
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authState.accessToken,
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
    })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log("========== [OK] [POST] IMAGE ==========");
    })

    .catch((error) => {
        if (error.response) {
            console.log("========== [ERROR] [POST] IMAGE ==========");
            console.log(error.response.data.data.error);
        } else {
            console.log('Error', error.message);
        }
        errorObject.status = 'KO';
        return errorObject;
    });

}
```

I get this error :

```
========== [ERROR] [POST] IMAGE ==========
Invalid URL ({"image":"file:/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540Johndoe%252Fphoto_finder/ImagePicker/0b453d00-189d-4ccb-840a-6215fff97d38.png"})
```

- There is no error in URL (works with Postman)
- I tried the request with different Content-Type
- If I remove the "data" field, I get this error :

```
"error": "No image data was sent to the upload api"
```

I don't know what how to move on with this "Invalid URL". Can you help me please ? Thank you very much.