# Degrading image taken using camera in cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap

I tried to upload captured image by using Cordova camera plugins with below options. After captured image render to image tag at the my image getting degrading. How to solve this issue? I tried with png/jpeg etc...

```
var options = {
    quality: 100,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    allowEdit: false,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JEPG,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
    correctOrientation: true
};
```

Please help me, thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with the DATA_URL destinationType and then show the image as base64, i'll give you an example:

```
var options = {
    quality: 100,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    allowEdit:false,
    saveToPhotoAlbum:false,
    correctOrientation: true
};

navigator.camera.getPicture(function cameraSuccess(imageUri) {
    var $image = document.getElementById('imageForTask');
    image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    console.log(imageData);

}, function cameraError(error) {
    console.debug("Unable to obtain picture: " + error, "app");

}, options);
```

Comment: Thanks for suggested .how to send image to server ?

Comment: Hi @DoddaNaveenKumar if this answer solved you problem mark it as accepted please, then if you have to send the image to a server you can look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34972072/how-to-send-image-to-server-with-http-post-in-javascript-and-store-base64-in-mon to get you started, in case you have other problems maybe ask another question with the server details and the languages/technologies you are using on the server-side

Comment: still iam getting degrading image only