# How to send an image to a server, from just the image url?

Tags: javascript, http

I am trying to send an image to a server for my chrome extension. I am using code from a previous discussion --> [how to send image to server with http.post in javascript and store base64 in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34972072/how-to-send-image-to-server-with-http-post-in-javascript-and-store-base64-in-mon).

My problem is that the image is never actually uploaded to the page. For instance, I am trying to upload the image to this input on server that is not mine: [image upload section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jvocr.png). After the code runs the image section is not uploaded with an image, which is ultimate goal of my program.

This is what the terminal looks like after all the console.log()'s run: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sullX.png)

Does anyone know the reason behind this and how I could fix this? Simply put, I want the desired image to be uploaded to "Add Photos" sections.

If anyone has a better solution to how approach the entirety of the problem, please let me know!

```
      var convertToBase64 = function(url, imagetype, callback){

          var img = document.createElement('IMG'),
              canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS'),
              ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
              data = '';

          // Set the crossOrigin property of the image element to 'Anonymous',
          // allowing us to load images from other domains so long as that domain
          // has cross-origin headers properly set

          img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous'

          // Because image loading is asynchronous, we define an event listening function that will be called when the image has been loaded
          img.onload = function(){
              console.log('hoiii');
              // When the image is loaded, this function is called with the image object as its context or 'this' value
              canvas.height = this.height;
              canvas.width = this.width;
              ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
              console.log(canvas);
              console.log(ctx);
              data = canvas.toDataURL(imagetype);
              console.log(data);
              callback(data);
          };

          // We set the source of the image tag to start loading its data. We define
          // the event listener first, so that if the image has already been loaded
          // on the page or is cached the event listener will still fire

          img.src = url;
          console.log(img);
      };

      // Here we define the function that will send the request to the server.
      // It will accept the image name, and the base64 data as arguments

      var sendBase64ToServer = function(name, base64){
          var httpPost = new XMLHttpRequest(),
              path = "data:image/png;base64,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",
              data = JSON.stringify({image: base64});
          httpPost.onreadystatechange = function(err) {
                  if (httpPost.readyState == 4 && httpPost.status == 200){
                      console.log(httpPost.responseText);
                  } else {
                      console.log(err);
                  }
              };
          // Set the content type of the request to json since that's what's being sent
          httpPost.open("POST", path, true);
          httpPost.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
          httpPost.send(data);
      };

      // This wrapper function will accept the name of the image, the url, and the
      // image type and perform the request

      var uploadImage = function(src, name, type){
          convertToBase64(src, type, function(data){
              sendBase64ToServer(name, data);
          });
      };

      // Call the function with the provided values. The mime type could also be png
      // or webp

      uploadImage(result.products[pointer][3], 'cool.jpeg', 'image/jpeg');
```

Comment: I think you want 'setRequestHeader', not 'setHeader'.

Comment: @ShaneMarotta - if I try to connect to my localhost before I've started XAMPP, the same connection-refused message is my reward.

Comment: Did you find a solution? @enhzflep

Comment: @ShaneMarotta - uh-huh. Introduce the palm of my hand to my face, then start the server and try again... I noted your original question contained the following string: `http://127.0.0.1:8000` - (please, forgive my question) Um, are you certain your server is listening on port 8000? Since the default is 80, you'd have had to start the server with a direction (or some pre-configured option) to use port 8000. Listening on the wrong port would reward you with the message you saw. (as would a bunch of other scenarios)

Comment: Is there a way to find out what port the server is listening on? @enhzflep

Comment: Dunno. I suppose there'd have to be. I don't need to know for my situation. I simply use URLs without a port specifier. (the :80 or :8000 part). I start the apache server with the xampp control panel then hit `localhost/someUrlHere` - 127.0.0.1 and localhost each point to your own machine by default. Anyway, beyond the scope of this question and the comments.