# Runtime for LRU cache problem quite high?

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, lru

I just tried [the LRU cache problem on Leetcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34972072/how-to-send-image-to-server-with-http-post-in-javascript-and-store-base64-in-mon) for the first time and am getting a horrific runtime (7800 ms). As far as I can tell other than the while loop in evictOldestUsed(), I have get() and set() operating at O(1), so am not sure where my bottleneck is. I'm sure I'm not approaching the problem in an ideal way but was hoping to fix my initial solution first before adopting a totally new approach.

Anyone have any idea why my solution is so slow? I'm not sure why I need the while loop in evictOldestUsed() as the accessesRecord should only have items that are in the LRU cache dict as well given that when I the least used record I also evict it from the accessesRecord.

```py
class LRUCache:

    def __init__(self, capacity: int):
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.LRU = {}
        self.accessesRecord = {}
        self.accessNumber = 1
        
    def updateAccessList(self, key: int):
        self.accessesRecord[key] = self.accessNumber
        self.accessNumber += 1
        
    def evictOldestUsed(self):
        oldestUsed = min(self.accessesRecord, key=self.accessesRecord.get)
        while self.LRU.get(oldestUsed) is None:
            self.accessesRecord.pop(oldestUsed)
            oldestUsed = min(self.accessesRecord, key=self.accessesRecord.get)
        self.LRU.pop(oldestUsed)
        
    def get(self, key: int) -> int:
        self.updateAccessList(key)
        return self.LRU.get(key, -1)

    def put(self, key: int, value: int) -> None:
        if self.LRU.get(key) is None and len(self.LRU) == self.capacity:
            self.evictOldestUsed()
        self.LRU[key] = value
        self.updateAccessList(key)
```

Comment: Seems like you pasted the wrong link to Leetcode. Try [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/lru-cache/)?

Comment: Also, your put() method is not O(1), even discarding the while loop. Every call to put() after the cache has been filled takes `O(|cache|)` because of the `min` call in evictOldestUsed. This is basically a brute-force approach to LRU caching.

Comment: `evictOldestUsed` doesn't actually removes from the `accesssRecord`. Also, it's not actually an LRU, if you add a new key it starts at 1 on the access counter and then will be immediately removed.